# Socket.io - Maintaining socket connection (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am making an iOS application in which I am using socket.io. The scenario is very simple, a person books an adventure i.e sending data using **emit** command. After that, i have used **socket.on** in order to get the response back from the server. This was working perfectly for sometime but now I am facing problems. Neither the data is reaching the server, nor response is coming back. 
I searched about this problem and the understanding I got is:

There is some point in which socket is getting disconnected and therefore the it stops working. I even used `socket.reconnect` before emitting data but it didn't work.

I found a parameter of `forceNew` for node.js but didn't find any of its alternative in swift.

Here is my code (related to socket.io):

In AppDelegate:

```
AppDelegate.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "######")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
AppDelegate.socket.connect ()
```

In ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        socket = AppDelegate.socket

          self.socket.on("book-adventure-seeker") {[weak self] data, ack in
              print (data)
         }
    }
    @IBAction func bookAdventureTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let jwtToken = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "jwtToken")

        let data = ["adventure_id": adventureId, "jwt": jwtToken] as [String : Any]
        self.socket.emit("book-adventure", data)
    }
```

And the log is:

```
2017-10-20 09:45:04.665 CuufyPrototype[2591:94370] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws:  has data: false
2017-10-20 09:45:08.541 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Emitting: 2["book-adventure",{"jwt":"######","adventure_id":"######"}]
2017-10-20 09:45:08.541 CuufyPrototype[2591:94370] LOG SocketEngine: Sending ws:  as type: 2
SocketIOClientStatus
2017-10-20 09:45:22.804 CuufyPrototype[2591:94370] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws: 2["book-adventure",{"jwt":"######","adventure_id":"#####"}] has data: false
2017-10-20 09:45:22.805 CuufyPrototype[2591:94370] LOG SocketEngine: Sending ws: 2["book-adventure",{"jwt":"#######","adventure_id":"######"}] as type: 4
2017-10-20 09:45:22.807 CuufyPrototype[2591:94370] LOG SocketEngine: Writing ws:  has data: false
2017-10-20 09:45:22.807 CuufyPrototype[2591:94370] LOG SocketEngine: Sending ws:  as type: 2
2017-10-20 09:45:22.810 CuufyPrototype[2591:93661] ERROR SocketEngine: 
2017-10-20 09:45:22.811 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] ERROR SocketIOClient: 
2017-10-20 09:45:22.811 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: error with data: [""]
2017-10-20 09:45:22.811 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: statusChange with data: [SocketIO.SocketIOClientStatus]
2017-10-20 09:45:22.812 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Starting reconnect
2017-10-20 09:45:22.812 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: reconnect with data: [""]
2017-10-20 09:45:22.812 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Trying to reconnect
2017-10-20 09:45:22.812 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data: [-1]
2017-10-20 09:45:22.812 CuufyPrototype[2591:93618] LOG SocketIOClient: Handling event: statusChange with data: [SocketIO.SocketIOClientStatus]
```

Even i tried to use `socket.on` in AppDelegate like this: (as in example from official docs)

```
AppDelegate.socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: URL(string: "#######")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])

        AppDelegate.socket.on("book-adventure-seeker") {[weak self] data, ack in
            print (data)
        }
  AppDelegate.socket.connect ()
```

But still it didn't work for me.

**Update:** Sometimes while on emit command, `Engine is being closed` appears in log but I am not getting any clue how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this code for `forceNew` in swift:

```
let config : [String: Any] = ["log": true,
                                  "compress": true,
                                  "forcePolling": true,
                                  "forceNew": true]
    var socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: url, config: config)
    var socket: SocketIOClient = socketManager.defaultSocket
```